# Is there a way to specify size of array in base class in inherited class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have an abstract base class which contains an array as well as two or more inherited classes which would like to have a slightly larger array in the base-class.

I tried to solve this by using templates:

```
template <int arraySize>
class Baseclass {
public:
    uint16_t arr[arraySize];
};

class InheritedClass :
    public Baseclass <5> {};
```

The issue I face now are:
Whenever I use a pointer to some Baseclass-Object, the compiler complains:

> argument list for class template "Baseclass " is missing

I think I understand what is going on here: Baseclass without the template parameter isn't now a complete type - however the compiler requires one.

Therefore I wonder - is there a (better) way of achieving what I am trying to do, without allocating the array in the InheritedClass and pass pointers down to Baseclass?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use a vector instead of an array.

Comment: Your code will work but it sounds like you try to use a pointer-to-template (`Baseclass*`) instead of a pointer-to-base-class. Of course that doesn’t work: *a template is not a type*.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: The attempt to use `Baseclass *` probably stems from the desire to have a single common base class in the hierarchy. And it is probably what's actually required.

Comment: @user2923748: In order to understand "what you are trying to do" we need to know whether you care to have a single common base class in your hierarchy or not. Do you?

Comment: Thanks, I solved this issue by defining a non-generic baseclass with virtual functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have `Baseclass` derive from a non-template class, and use a pointer to that instead.

Answer (score 5):

If the array is directly embedded into the base class, as in your example, then it is not possible to specify the size of that array. More precisely, changing the size of that array will require generating a completely different version of that base class for each specific array size. This will defeat the purpose, since your intent, apparently, is to have a single common base class in the hierarchy. Is it?

This is exactly the problem you run into with your template "solution". Your program doesn't have a common `Baseclass` anymore. Instead you have `Baseclass<5>`, `Baseclass<10>` and so on - all completely different, independent base classes. And this is not what you need, apparently.

The only way to achieve a common base class with run-time sized array in it is to store the array in the base class *indirectly*. I.e. declare a `uint16_t *` pointer in the base class and allocate the proper amount of memory at run time. Or you can simply use `std::vector<uint16_t>` instead of raw array.

Note that if you decide to go the pointer way, it is not absolutely required to allocate the array memory dynamically. You can simply make the actual "array memory" a member of the derived class which already "knows" the specific size

```
class Baseclass {
public:
  uint16_t *arr;
  size_t arraySize;

  Baseclass(uint16_t *arr, size_t arraySize) : arr(arr), arraySize(arraySize)
    {}
};

class InheritedClass : public Baseclass
{
  InheritedClass() : Baseclass(arr_memory, 5)
    {}
private:
  uint16_t arr_memory[5];
};
```

So, the bottom line is, if you want the array memory management to be incapsulated entirely into `Baseclass`, then you have no other choice but to allocate the memory dynamically at run-time. If that is not acceptable, then you are restricted to performing memory management elsewhere and passing it down to `Baseclass` from outside.

Comment: question author mentioned that their requirements limit using dynamic memory for the array in the Base Class !

Comment: Sure, changing the size will generate a new type - which is what I am heading for. 

What I did now is to specify an abstract base class with virtual methods which accesses the dynamic array. This way I work with the base type, while at run-time the correct compile-time implementation is chosen for a given type.

I forgot to mention: pointers are also bad, because the class is serialized (copied from one place to another) and pointers would break this.

Thanks a lot for your detailed answer :)

Comment: @user2923748: Buy using an abstract base class you simply shifted the implementation from "data pointers" to "code pointers". The latter are not explicitly visible, but they are there. In the end, both will make you deal with fairly similar issues with serialization.

Answer (score 1):

As a hack that will probably work, include a method in `baseclass` that `reinterpret_cast`s `this` into `baseclass<1>`.

This relies on your ty0es being compiled into relatively sane layouts: to encourage that to happen, ensure that `baseclass` is pod or standard layout at the least.

While the result is undefined behaviour, in every compiler I have used it will work.

The downside?  How big is your array must be transported in parallel, and you lie to other users of your class about the runtime array size.  Plus it is extremely fragile: the array must be the last element of `baseclass`.

You are probably better off doing away with the compile time static bounds, and storing a `std::vector` with runtime bounds, as that will avoid undefined behavior hacks and reduce the lies per line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Baseclass {
public:
    uint16_t *arr;
    Baseclass(int arrlen) {
        arr = new int[arrlen];
    }

    ~Baseclass() {
        delete arr;
    }

};

class InheritedClass :
    public Baseclass {
public:
    Inherited() : Baseclass(5){
    }
};
```

If you can, you can simply use dynamic allocation.

Comment: I can't use dynamic allocation, that is why I also can't use std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly specify an argument, C++ ignores the default expression.  So in your derived classes you specify your [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)'d base's needs explicitly, but in the base you also supply a default-value calculation to be used (only) after instantiation.
So:

```
#include <iostream>
// instantiation specifies size explicitly, default calculation ignored
// after instantiation names in default calculation are bound correctly

template<class d,int size=sizeof d::m2/sizeof *d::m2>
struct b {
        int m[size];
};

struct d: b<d,20> {
        double m2[20];
};

int main() {
        std::cout<<sizeof b<d>::m/sizeof *b<d>::m<<'\n';
}
```